# How to make a POST request to servers that was deployed with balancing over https domain?

Tags: post, meteor, https, load-balancing, mailchimp

I had 3 servers with balancing: server-1.test.com, server-2.test.com, server3.test.com.

And I used domain https://test.com.

I want to make a POST request such as : curl -X POST https://test.com -d "title=test"

After that, if the post request was redirect by balancing to server-1.test.com. it would be ok. But if not, it would be change to GET request. So I couldn't get data from GET request. I knew that problem from https redirect. Any suggestions for it?

I can't use GET request for replace POST. because it was made by webhook of mailchimp.

Answer (score 0):

For http call you can user [http](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/http) package in meteor.

You can also refer the [themeteorchef](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/using-the-http-package/#tmc-the-http-package) tutorial for more understanding for http in meteor.

One more thing for http calls meteor uses sync call. So you can also use wrapasync in meteor for http calls for sending response back to client.

Comment: your answer isn't related with my question. Did you know about balancing, mailchimp, ssl  before make the answer?